# Does a phrase make a sentence complex?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrases

I'm confused whether a phrase is making a sentence complex or it still a simple one? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Soufiane, welcome to ELL! This is a good question, but it's a little bit hard to answer with the details you have provided here. Could you maybe [edit](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/83150/edit) your question to add more details about what you mean, or maybe some example sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what kind of phrase (clause) is added.

If it is a **dependent clause** then yes, the sentence becomes **complex**

If it is an **independent clause** then no, the sentence becomes **compound**